# create dynamic billing button

Tags: php, paypal

I want to create dynamic billing button using paypal

when  I used create button at the paypal.com it generate a button for me :

```
           <form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top'>
       <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_s-xclick'>
       <input type='hidden' name='hosted_button_id' value='BFKATLSGW6CTW'>
      <input type='image' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'>

      <img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1'>
      </form>
```

but it's with a static price

I tried to add  a hidden input

```
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.95">
```

but the price still static

I tried the automatic billing throw the paypal.com 
but I got

> You need to have a PayPal Business account and the Enhanced Recurring Payments package to create Automatic Billing or Installment Plan buttons

I viewd my profile and created a  business app for it , but the message still the same

My last try  to use this form

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

 <!-- Identify your business so that you can bill for payments. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="BLWHUxxxxxx"> <!-- I put my merchant  id---->

        <!-- Specify an Automatic Billing button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-auto-billing">

        <!-- Specify details about the automatic billing plan. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Regular House Cleaning">
        <input type="hidden" name="max_text" value="Regular House Cleaning">
        <input type="hidden" name="set_customer_limit" value="max_limit_own">
        <input type="hidden" name="min_amount" value="1.00">



        <!-- Make sure you get the buyer's address during checkout. -- >
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">

        <!-- Display the description and a text box to enter the maximum. -->
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><strong> </strong></td></tr>
        <tr><td> 
         </td></tr>
        <tr><td>$ 
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.95">
        <input type="text" name="max_amount" value="1000"> USD</td></tr>

        <!-- Inform buyers of the monthly minimum payment -->
        <tr><td> </td></tr>
        </table>

        <!-- Display the Automatic Billing button -->
        <table>

        <tr><td><input type="image" border="0" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
        alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"></td></tr>
        </table>
        <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" />
        </form>
```

but the result is

> This merchant is no longer authorized to offer this Autobilling plan.Please contact the merchant or choose another product.

any recommendations to have a script that take the price from the database to let the customer pay for the the services !

Answer (score 0):

You are using Hosted button. It is not possible to over-write the amount value in `Hosted Button` . You can can clear text button to over-write the amount variable.
When you create a button in Paypal, make sure you uncheck the option "Save button at PayPal" in Step 2 . This makes the button "Clear Text" and provides option to over-write any variable using your custom logic.Automatic billing,Installments button work only if you have `Enhanced Recurring Payments` [**ERP**](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/erp_overview) [image]